# Php ini_set mail smtp

Tags: php, email

How and where to insert script for php ini_set mail smtp
i create wiki for my site but whan some one register it need to receive mail to confirm registration but whan some one try to register he get this message:

```
wiki could not send your confirmation mail. Please check your e-mail address for invalid characters. 

Mailer returned: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()
```

so i will not edit php.ini i need script for `ini_set()` pls help

Answer (score 2):

Your mail server might not be running. Contact your system administrator and ask to check if the mail server is running on 127.0.0.1:25

Comment: also: I believe, by default `smtp` and `smtp_port` default to 127.0.0.1 and 25. So it's more likely that the server itself is down or not started.

Comment: this is my local network and im system admin so can you expl where to look to start up mail server txn for reply 
i whant to use my gmail acc to send mail how to do that

Comment: It depends on your distribution and what MTA that is installed. Most distros come with sendmail and your best bet would be simply ask PHP to send mail via that. 

Edit your PHP config and set the sendmail path

`sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail`

Replace the path to reflect whats there on your system (type `which sendmail` in your shell to figure out the path)